# How many cubes are in each Desmond sequence?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

There are some spinning cubes hidden in the Desmond sequences of *Assassin's Creed Revelations*, I was wondering how many are in each sequence?

I found 2 in the first sequence and 1 (#4) in the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is confirmed that there are 2 in each sequence.
 If you want to know how to get them, here is [a link](http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Assassin's_Creed:_Revelations_-_PC_PS3_XB360/Desmond's_Journey).

Answer (score 7):

I found two in five so I'm guessing two each, and that one was numbered 10 in the final room on five so happy hunting

Comment: This seems to be the case.